# Create Mongodb Atlas Triggers Programmatically | Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-stitch

I am planning to create few triggers in mongodb atlas using nodejs. I found [mongodb-stitch-server-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-stitch-server-sdk) library which kind of helps me to connect to stitch application but I couldn't find anything which can help me create a trigger.

Can anyone point me to write documentation or example to do so? I am open to use API as well if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a POST to `/groups/{groupid}/apps/{appid}/triggers`.
Triggers API docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/admin/api/admin-v3/#event-trigger-apis

Comment: that link is broken

Comment: by the way I created a nodejs package to do this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-stitch-api-client